# pod spec lint error - [iOS] xcodebuild: error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:

Tags: ios, validation, cocoapods, swift5

When I do, `pod spec lint`, I get following validation error.

```
 [Framework-Name] (1.0.0)
        - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
        - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
        - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in parallel
        - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file '[Framework-Name]/[Framework-Name]/[Framework-Name].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata' of type 'text.xml' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Framework-Name' from project 'Pods')
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file '[Framework-Name/Framework-Name/Framework-Name].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' of type 'text.pbxproject' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Framework-Name' from project 'Pods')
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file '[Framework-Name/Framework-Name/Framework-Name].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata' of type 'text.xml' for architecture 'i386' (in target 'Framework-Name' from project 'Pods')
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'Framework-Name/Framework-Name/Framework-Name.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' of type 'text.pbxproject' for architecture 'i386' (in target 'Framework-Name' from project 'Pods')
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file '[Framework-Name/Framework-Name/Framework-Name].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata' of type 'text.xml' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Framework-Name' from project 'Pods')
        - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file '[Framework-Name/Framework-Name/Framework-Name].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' of type 'text.pbxproject' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Framework-Name' from project 'Pods')

Analyzed 1 podspec.
```

don't know, what is going on here. I followed the instruction step by step.

Here is my spec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "[Framework-Name]"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "Framework-Name summary"
  s.homepage     = "[Github path for framework]"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = { "Author Name" => "author_email@gmail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "10.0"
  s.swift_version = "5.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "[Github path for framework].git", :tag => "1.0.0" }
  s.source_files  = "[Framework-Name]/**/*"
  s.exclude_files = "[Framework-Name]/**/*.plist"
end
```

I couldn't find anything that can help.

Comment: The `--verbose` and `--no-clean` options can help to investigate

Comment: It's probably problematic to include the Xcode project files in the `s.source_file` expression

Comment: That was the issue. explicitly included only the .h, .m and .swift and it worked. Can you please post your comment as an answer. This was a huge help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xcode project files in the podspec's `s.source_file` expression should only reference the source files.

Xcode project files and other non-source files should not be included.